# Trying to install Funtoo (inside VirtualBox only for now, for testing) with ZFS for boot/root - failed install and booting

Tags: linux, boot, root, zfs, funtoo

Following guide

https://www.funtoo.org/ZFS_Install_Guide

everything works great, until in section "Create optional Datasets" at "Build directory":

```
zfs create -o mountpoint=/var/tmp/portage -o compression=lz4 -o sync=disabled rpool/FUNTOO/build
```

which results in the error message:

> cannot create 'rpool/FUNTOO/build': parent does not exist

I tried

```
zfs create -o mountpoint=/var/tmp/portage -o compression=lz4 -o sync=disabled rpool/FUNTOO
```

and then

```
zfs create -o mountpoint=/var/tmp/portage -o compression=lz4 -o sync=disabled rpool/FUNTOO/build
```

and no error messages at that point, but later down, after "chrooting" (I think it was when creating the initramfs in section "Create a ZFS-friendly initramfs") there's a warning or error. The rest of the install (including grub) then finishes without any errors though.

However, after finishing the install and "exit"ing the "chroot", then trying to unmount (export) the zfs pool ("zpool export rpool"), it'd say that the device is in use / busy and can not be unmounted. Hitting CTRL-ALT-DEL or "reboot" clears the screen and shows a black screen with a blinking cursor, without the VM restarting and has to be "cold-started".

After booting, a message would state that the root / boot can not be found.

Anyone knowledgeable in those things know what is going wrong and how to fix it?